# How to set color area when value is 10 is green , if value is 50 and upper is yellow, and if value is 100 and upper is red use Apexcharts

Tags: apexcharts

I want to make custom color apexchart in type area, the problem is color even changed
Here are the code function:

```
getColor(value:number): string {
        if (value > 100) {
          return '#FF0000'; // Red color for values above 100
        } else if (value >50) {
          return '#FFA500'; // yellow color for values above 50
        } else {
          return '#008000'; // Green color for other values
        }
      }
```

and implement in chart

```
colors: [this.getColor],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        fill: {
            colors: [this.getColor],
            opacity: 0.5
        },
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/V16aO.png